# C# can't access WPF object in websocket?

Tags: c#, wpf

I assume this is a scoping issue... but I'm not that good with C# so I need help...

Firstly, I have a tabControl in my XAML:

```
<TabControl x:Name="tabControl" x:FieldModifier="public" />
```

Items in this TabControl are added dynamically in code. Each tab has a "content" field which is added based on a bunch of UserControls. IE: `tab.Content = new TextFields(this);`

Somewhere else in my code, I can do the following to echo out the names of all my tabs:

```
foreach (TabItem item in tabControl.Items)
{
    MessageBox.Show(item.Name.ToString());
}
```

So far this all works great. However, now I am trying to access my tabs through WebSockets. Basically, I want the end user to be able to type in a tab name, and if that tab exists, execute a function in that tab's UserControl such as `getTabData`.

Just for basic testing, I moved the above `foreach` into my WebSocket:

```
var sockets = new List<Fleck.IWebSocketConnection>();
var websock = new Fleck.WebSocketServer("ws://0.0.0.0:58341");
websock.Start(socket =>
{
    socket.OnOpen = () => sockets.Add(socket);
    socket.OnClose = () => sockets.Remove(socket);
    socket.OnMessage = message =>
    {
        sockets.ToList().ForEach(s => s.Send("Echo: " + message));
        foreach (TabItem item in tabControl.Items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(item.Name.ToString());
        }
    };
});
```

Unfortunately, the MessageBox function just seems to outright fail as the name of each tab seems to be null. It knows the number of tabs in the tab control, but it can't seem to get the name of the tabs or the contents of the tabs. How can I fix this?

The websocket is in MainWindow.cs, and the TabControl is in MainWindow.xaml

Comment: There is too much information missing, where is your websocket? On the xaml control you show us? Did you check if a message is sent? Did you check if your tabControl filled in your onMessage treatment? Where your tabControl is initialized?

Comment: For a start you must be careful accessing UI objects from arbitrary threads (p.s. you can't!), e.g. you don't know what thread `socket.OnMessage` is using.  It could also be a race condition between initializing tabs and arrival of first message.  If you don't know what `Dispatcher` is better start researching... https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: I've updated my OP with more information. The websocket is correctly echoing my message back to me, but its not popping up the messageboxes because `item.Name` is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing a UI control cross-thread; use `Dispatcher.Invoke`:

```
        foreach (TabItem item in tabControl.Items)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(Dispatcher.Invoke(() => item.Name));
        }
```

Comment: That worked perfect! Now I just need to figure out how to run a function from the UserControl. Do you mind if I PM you to pick your brain?

Comment: @JasonAxelrod, Sure thing! In meetings today a bit, but will get back to you as soon as I can. :)

Comment: @JasonAxelrod, me neither, I thought you did, lol - go ahead and make a new post, and link it in a comment here.